# RABA (רבה) Bar Rav Shila or RAVA (רבא) Bar Rav Shila?

Tags: names, talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot, amoroim

On the Talmud (Brachot- ברכות דף ב ע"א) there are a two versions:

> 1. Ra**V**a bar Rav Shila (**רבא** בר רב שילא)
> 2. Ra**B**a Bar Rav Shila (**רבה** בר רב שילא)

What is the right version?

Comment: I can give you a link to a copy of a Yemenite manuscript of the Talmud and you can look to see how it's written there?

Comment: Of course. Give it to me and I'll tell you. But why do you think that if we find one of two options in this script it will help us to know what is the correct version?

Comment: i can't guarantee to you that it will definitively say which is the correct version. But the Yemenite manuscripts are cited for their authenticity and many scholars say that the Yemenite manuscripts are more accurate because their copyists made less errors, while many other communities used copyists that were barely literate and needed to make a living

Comment: Turns out i can't give you a direct link, but you can make a free online account and go looking for yourself :D http://www.genizah.org/onlineFGP.htm?type=Nachum&lang=eng

Comment: Actually I was in this site before I asked my question here.  There are a lot of version in these scripts (look for instance, in Muinchen script). Unfortunately, they are with a lot of mistakes.